# Finally block is not executed in this code

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

The finally block in this code doesn't execute at all.

I have wrote this code to prevent assigning a None value to the current object, so I came up with an idea to use finally and assign this object with the previous state, but when I execute it the finally block doesn't execute at all (I have added a print statement to see if it's executed and it's not).

```py
def __idiv__(self, other):
        try:
            if other is None:
                raise ValueError('The second number is None')
            if not isinstance(other, Complex):
                other = Complex(other)
            den = other * other.con()
            num = self * other.con()
            re = num.re / den.re
            im = num.im / den.re
            return Complex(re, im)
        except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError) as err:
            print(colored('{}: {}'.format(err.__class__.__name__, err), 'red'))
        finally:
            print('-'*80)
            return Complex(self.re, self.im)
```

When I call this method I just get this without the output of print statement in finally block:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Why not just check if the denominator equals 0 rather than forcing you to catch the exception? Also, there's some rules around if the finally block contains a return statement https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to check directly the denominator. Thanks.

Comment: But even so, shouldn't the finally block be executed?